# very simple: 1/20 returns 0.0

Tags: java, processing

In Processing I have this code:

```
int numberOfSteps = 20;
float numberOfStepsCalculated = (1/20);
println(numberOfStepsCalculated);
```

But my print keeps returning 0.0

I can not figure out why!

Thanks for my dumb question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer divison.

```
float numberOfStepsCalculated = (1.0f / numberOfSteps); // 20
```

When you divide two `int`(s) the result is an `int` (or `0`). You then widen the result to a `float` (or `0.0`). Promote one of the values in the calculation to a `float` and you'll get a `float` result.

Comment: Ah that was it! I knew it was something like that! I have upvoted you, but is there anything else I should do to this thread (i.e. mark resolved, e.t.c.)

Comment: @user2122995 I suggest that you [edit your profile](/users/edit/current) and give yourself a name! Also, yes - you can [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/243725).